# Intermittent noise from Audio interface

Tags: audio-recording, noise, audio-interfaces, guitar

I bought a new Steinberg UR22 about a week ago to get to start doing some recording but straight away ran into problems.
I tried it out recording into garage band but I started getting loud intermittent buzzing when i used almost any software amp, 
i thought it was my guitar but i ended up finding that the buzzing was present all the time just at a lower volume even without any instruments plugged in.

could anyone tell me where the noise is coming from?

Comment: Fluorescent lights, old CRT screen… fridge… only test for external interference is to move it around & see where it's loudest

Comment: If you are using a laptop, try to unplug the power and work only with the battery.

Comment: @Tetsujin What about unplugging any electronic devices to eliminate them?

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if all powered devices are grounded within the same circuit. Also, keep cell phones or any other wireless devices away from speakers too.